# CPU Log parsing, grouping and reporting

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, priority-queue, treemap

Following is a sample of a log file read, includes: JobStatus:(Finished, Processing), JobName, InstanceName, Duration.
The sequence of events is NOT guaranteed.

Using Java, what is the most efficient way of parsing this log file entirely and reporting the name of each jobName and longest duration it took to complete?    What data structures would you use?

```
 HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>
 or
 List<HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>>
```

How would you print the final results sorted between different jobNames?

```
Sample Input:
--------------
"Processing jobName=execute    jobInstanceId=x1"
"Processing jobName=execute    jobInstanceId=y1"
"Finished   jobInstanceId=x1   duration=920"
"Finished   jobInstanceId=y1   duration=12009"
"Finished   jobInstanceId=z1   duration=50"
"Processing jobName=analyze    jobInstanceId=z1"

Expected Output:
--------------
execute  12009
analyze  50
```

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. I suggest you break it down. Start with parsing. Once you can parse it, then worry about how to interpret the information. Give it some thought, then post specific, narrowly-targeted questions.

Comment: There are so many options passing log/flat files in java. research needed.

Comment: Thank you @JimMischel, I should have been more clear with the ask.  The issue is not parsing. The challenge is what DS would you recommend parsing the data into, such that we could find the largest duration of jobInstance from every jobName and print it in sorted order.  What is the most efficient way to avoid defining unnecessary DSs and consuming unnecessary space? What sequence would you parse what info into what exact DS? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest thing first.

1. Define a class that holds the necessary information.
2. Create an empty `List` of that class type.
3. Parse each record into an instance of that class, and add it to the list.
4. Sort the list by job name (ascending), and duration (descending).
5. Go through the list sequentially and output the first record for each job name.

That's straightforward, simple, reasonably efficient, and shouldn't use too much memory.

You have a little bit of a complication in that a record actually occupies two lines that are not necessarily one right after the other. But you said that parsing it isn't a problem, so I assume you know how to handle that.

The only problem you might run into is if the log file contains so many entries that you can't hold everything in memory. If that's the case, then you can either get creative and keep only the current longest duration entry for each job name or, rather than keeping the list in memory, write it to disk. Then sort the disk file and go through it sequentially.

Do the simplest thing you think will work. If it works, doesn't run out of memory, and completes quickly enough, then you're done. Don't worry about optimizing for space or speed. Move on to other, more important, things.